# Would the Genii's plan actually have failed?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

The in *Stargate: Atlantis* season 1 episode 7 [“Underground”](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Underground) we meet the Genii. Their plan is to build nuclear weapons, place them on all the hibernating Wraith ships, and take them all down at once. They are planning for about 50 more years of preparation to be able to do this. Dr Weir says that there plan would never work "With or without our help." Implying that a coordinated strike at 60+ targets at once was unfeasible.

In less than 50 years, the US alone went from 3 warheads to over 2000, and were capable of delivering multiple warheads at the same time. Even if the strikes were off by a few minutes, or even hours, the nukes being on board the Hive Ships would still be effective. This was shown by Daedalus when their transporters were still effective. The Wraith counter measures made the transporters not work, not the nuclear weapons.

It seems to me that the Genii's plan of a coordinated, or nearly coordinated, strike on the Wraith would indeed be successful, provided they had enough Uranium after 50 years of mining, and were able to accurately decode the Wraith information and find all the Hives. So, why would the plan not work?

Comment: It's certainly a highly ambitious plan but as we see, plenty of Wraith Hiveships are hibernating in deep space rather than on planets and are, for all intents, inaccessible to the Genii even had they known their precise locations. They might be able to deal the Wraith a blow but it wouldn't be a fatal one

Comment: I didn't remember that some of them hibernated in deep space. Good catch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The plan suffers from a number of flaws, none of which are easily resolved by a nation as backwards as the Genii.

**Counting down from top to bottom;**

1) Their plan relies on identifying the location of a large proportion of the wraith's hiveships. In later episodes we see that the Wraith have hiveships in hibernation at secret bases (like the one seen in SGA: Spoils of War) and in space. There's no possible way that the Genii could locate all of them or get to them.

2) Some planets have a [spacegate](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Spacegate) rather than a planet-based stargate. There's no obvious way that the Genii could access a hive on a planetary surface if they've got no ships.

3) Their plan relies on infiltrating potentially dozens of ships *by force simultaneously*, but without causing a general alarm transmitted to other wraith ships.

4) Their plan is basically ruined by the SGA waking the wraith. Their ships are now active (orbiting planets and moving around the galaxy) which makes them entirely immune to the kind of attack planned by the Genii.

Comment: *Their plan relies on identifying the location of a large proportion of the wraith's hiveships.* - Not exactly. Their plan relies on identifying **absolutely every single** hiveship. Just miss one or two and you are in very deep shit.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf  -I'll give them credit. Swatting even fifty percent of these ships would be a major victory but the retaliation would be epic too. The irony is the Genii wouldn't bear the brunt of that because of their underground bunkers

Comment: @Valorum A short-sighted, selfish, semi-paranoid plan? Sounds like Genii Military Tactics 101 stuff. :)

Comment: @Valorum It would be a major victory (for the rest of the galaxy), but the Genii are not depicted as being very altruistic. I don't think they would be willing to sacrifice their whole people for the benefit for the other humans in the galaxy. If just a few hiveships escape the attack, the Wraith would be *extremely* motivated to find out who was behind it. It doesn't matter if it takes them 50 or 100 years to find out, but eventually they will, and the underground bunkers will not save the Genii once the Wraith know where to look.

Comment: As the example of Sateda shows, the Wraith don't tolerate any human people that come even near to being able to successfully defend themselfes against the Wraith, let alone being able to attack them.

Answer (score 0):

The Wraith have two methods of communication. Telepathic and Subspace radio. Both of which appear to work faster than light and across interstellar, sometimes intergalactic distances.

The Genii were not aware of these facts, nor were they aware that the hibernating Wraith had been awakened by news of a plentiful source of food (Earth).

In order for the Genii's plan to succeed, they would have to covertly place nukes on every hive ship and detonate them all simultaneously.

The only way for the Genii to achieve this would be to provoke the Wraith into culling humans with nuclear warheads implanted inside them, and praying that every nuke was in place and not discovered when the synced up timers went off.

Since the Genii had never recovered a culled human before teaming up with SGA, they did not know any of those facts. Thus, without the help of SGA, they would have delivered nukes through stargates where they thought hive ships would be and found that their targets were either awake and on alert, or gone culling.